# python + beautiful soup, navigating the parse tree without the aid of attributes?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

i'm trying to scrape text from this page:
http://codingbat.com/prob/p187868

specifically, i want to scrape two strings from the page, to combine as the key in a dictionary with the problem statement as value. these are the two parts of the name of the problem (here: 'Warmup-1' and 'sleepin'). however, the strings are contained in different levels of the parse tree and this is creating problems.

abstractly, the problem is this:

i'm trying to scrape text from a parse tree of:

div-->{[a[span'h2'[string1]]], [span'h2'[string2]], some other tags}

since they are both contained in 'span' tags with the attribute class='h2', i can scrape a list of these and then select from the list.

```
div_nameparts = name_div.find_all('span', class_='h2')
name1 = div_nameparts[0].string
name2 = div_nameparts[1].string
problem_name = name1+' > '+name2
print(problem_name)
```

but what if those tags didn't share an attribute like they do here ('h2')?

if i try to navigate the parse tree using div.a.string, i can get the first tag - string1. but div.span.string does not return the second value (string2).

```
name1 = name_div.a.string
name2 = name_div.span.string
```

instead it again returns the first (string1), apparently navigating to div.a.span (the child of a child) and stopping, before finding its way to div.span (the next child).

and if i try div.a.next_sibling to try to navigate to div.span and get the string with div.span.string,

```
name1 = name_div.a.string
name2_div = name_div.a.next_sibling
name2 = name2_div.string
```

it returns an empty string, a value of None.

is there a better/effective way to get to navigate the parse tree to get to these span tags?

thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand why you're not satisfied with your code, it is very effective. I guess you could use `select('span.h2')` but that's basically the same thing. The html code can be verry different from page to page even for pages on the same site. There is no 'universal' method for web-scraping, it's whatever works best every time.

Comment: thanks t.m.adam, i see what you're saying. but i ran into the limits of my understanding and am looking forward to future cases. i was calling methods and encountering unexpected behaviors and hoping someone could explain why the methods were producing the results they were.

Answer (score 0):

This'll work as long as the 'greater than' symbol (' > ') with leading and trailing space doesn't appear before the pair of strings you want:

```
gt = soup.find(text=' > ')
string1 = gt.findPrevious('span').text
string2 = gt.findNext('span').text

print(string1, gt, string2, sep='')
```

The output:

```
Warmup-1 > sleepIn
```

Comment: thanks, mahesh, that's an elegant solution. thank you for pointing it out. for the more general case, i think the solution for me will be to use scrapy and xpath selectors rather than bs4 and css selectors.